# How do I add the folder name to the file being created in my batch file?

Tags: batch-file, copy

I'm using -

```
for /d /r %%a in (*) do (
    del "%%~fa\COMBINED_NAD.TXT" >nul 2>nul 
    copy /b "%%~fa\*NAD.TXT" "%%~fa\COMBINED_NAD.TMP"
    ren "%%~fa\COMBINED_NAD.TMP" "COMBINED_NAD.TXT"
)
```

Which works great, but I also need it to include the directory folder name in the file it is creating - for example I want the output to be something like - "`%DIR%_COMBINED_NAD.TXT`".

Does anyone know what I need to add? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't know the exact format you want.  If it was in a path like `C:\Users\Example\Documents\‍`, what do you want the file name to be?  `DOCUMENTS_COMBINED_NAD.TXT`?  `USERS_EXAMPLE_DOCUMENTS_COMBINED_NAT.TXT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the output you want, there's several possible solutions.

---

1. Excludes base directory.

If the program was run in `C:\Users\Example\Documents\`, and was in the folder `C:\Users\Example\Documents\Example\Something\`, the result would be `Example_Something_COMBINED_NAD.TXT`.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /d /r %%a in (*) do (
    del "%%~fa\COMBINED_NAD.TXT" >nul 2>nul 
    copy /b "%%~fa\*NAD.TXT" "%%~fa\COMBINED_NAD.TMP"
    set dir=%%~fa
    set dir=!dir:%cd%\=!
    set dir=!dir:\=_!
    ren "%%~fa\COMBINED_NAD.TMP" "!dir!_COMBINED_NAD.TXT"
)
```

The important bit here is this:

```
set dir=%%~fa
set dir=!dir:%cd%\=!
set dir=!dir:\=_!
```

The first line sets `dir` to `%%~fa`, which is the folder currently being processed.
The second line replaces all occurences of the value of `%cd%` (the directory in which the program was started) to `‍` (blank) inside of `dir`.
The third line replaces all slashes with underscores.  (File names can't have slashes in them)

Note that this uses `!varname!` rather than `%varname%`.  This is explained in the help for `set`, and is why `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is needed.

---

2. Includes base directory.

If the program was run in `C:\Users\Example\Documents\`, and was in the folder `C:\Users\Example\Documents\Example\Something\`, the result would be `Users_Example_Documents_Example_Something_COMBINED_NAD.TXT`.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /d /r %%a in (*) do (
    del "%%~fa\COMBINED_NAD.TXT" >nul 2>nul 
    copy /b "%%~fa\*NAD.TXT" "%%~fa\COMBINED_NAD.TMP"
    set dir=%%~pa
    set dir=!dir:\=_!
    set dir=!dir:~1!
    ren "%%~fa\COMBINED_NAD.TMP" "!dir!_COMBINED_NAD.TXT"
)
```

The important bit here is this:

```
set dir=%%~pa
set dir=!dir:\=_!
set dir=!dir:~1!
```

It's very similar to the first one, but a few changes have been made.

The first line sets `dir` to the folder but not the drive letter.
The second line replaces slashes with underscores (same reason as above).
The third line sets dir to 1 char into dir.  This is needed as otherwise it would output with a leading underscore.

---

I do not know of a solution that produces `Something_COMBINED_NAD.TXT` if the program was run in `C:\Users\Example\Documents\`, and was in the folder `C:\Users\Example\Documents\Example\Something\`.